# Python 2 __getattr__ max recursion depth

Tags: python, getattr

for example i use this code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict1 = {
            'A': 3,
            'B': self.A}
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self.dict1:
            return self.dict1[key]
a = A()
```

and when it's runned it throws maximum recursion depth exceeded.
Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong here

Answer (score 13):

The reference to `self.dict1` inside your `__getattr__` method causes `__getattr__` to be called again, and so on, hence the infinite recursion. The only safe way to access attributes of `self` inside `__getattr__` is by using references to `self.__dict__`. Try

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    if key in self.__dict__['dict1']:
        return self.__dict__['dict1'][key]
```

Note also that the absence of an `else` clause will mean undefined attributes appear to have the value `None`.

Comment: Tried you solution and it raise KeyError instead

Comment: That's because in trying to construct `self.dict1` in the `__init__` method you attempt tp access `self.A`. This triggers a call to `__getattr__`, which assumes the existence of `self.dict1`.

Comment: Maybe not very ellegant, but it works if i just set 'B' after dict1 is created
like this:
`self.dict1['B'] = self.A`

Comment: As long as you've got something that works. Elegance can come later!

Comment: Don't forget as well that if you implement `__setattr__` the `__init__` method should use `self.__dict__['dict1'] = {}`.